# How do I create an instance of a Python subclass that inherits some attributes, but adds some of its own as well?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I am currently learning Python (using v3.7) and doing some exercises. I am working on a bank account manager, for which I want to create several account subclasses (CheckingAccount, SavingsAccount, etc.) from a main Account class. The Account class has a few attributes (account number, first + last name, balance) and methods that I want to pass down to the subclasses, but for each subclass I would like to add extra attributes (like a limit for checking accounts).

This is what my code looks like at the moment:

```py
class Account():
    def __init__(self, last_name, first_name, balance = 0):
        self.id = next(account_number)
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.balance = balance

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount
        print(f"${amount} was added to your account, your current balance is ${self.balance}")

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.balance -= amount
        print(f"${amount} was taken from your account, your current balance is ${self.balance}")

    def check_balance(self):
        print(f"Your current balance is ${self.balance}")

class CheckingAccount(Account):
    def __init__(self, limit = 1000):
        Account.__init__(self)
        self.limit = limit
```

What I'm trying to do now is create an instance of my subclass. My problem here is that my editor (VS Code 1.40.2) tells me that the `__init__` method in CheckingAccount only takes one positional argument: `(limit: int)`. I tried a few things here, to no avail:

**1. limit argument only:**

`c_acc1 = CheckingAccount(100)`

**or no argument** (since limit has a default value):

`c_acc1 = CheckingAccount()`

*Output:*

> TypeError: **init**() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'last_name' and 'first_name'

in `__init__ 
    Account.__init__(self)`

**2. added limit, first_name and last_name arguments including keywords:**

`c_acc1 = CheckingAccount(limit = 100, last_name = "Doe", first_name = "John")`

*Output:*

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'last_name'

**3. added arguments without keywords:**

`c_acc1 = CheckingAccount(100, "Doe", "John")`

*Output:*

> TypeError: **init**() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given

Is there any way to make this work like I want it to, or am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: Your Account class is written so that it requires a first and last name. You have given CheckingAccount an `__init__` method that does _not_ require a first and last name. CheckingAccount is an Account, so that does not make sense. If you want to initialise a CheckingAccount with a first and last name, you should write them as `__init__` parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I just figured this out for myself as well, it hit me as I was reading the question again after posting.